# Modern UI - How to make a link load its content in "_top"?

Tags: wpf, modern-ui

I have a `ModernTab` control, to which I'm dynamically adding a `Link`:

```
InstallationTab.Links.Add(new Link { DisplayName = "Review Configuration", Source = new Uri("/Views/InstallationProgress.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });
```

I'd like `InstallationProgress.xaml` to load in the top frame instead of the current content frame.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question, in case anyone else finds themselves here:

This is just one example of "hijacking" the click on the ModernTab. Here, you can force the content to load in the top frame, for example:

Handle the `SelectedSourceChanged` event of the ModernTab:

`MyModernTab.SelectedSourceChanged += MyModernTab_SelectedSourceChanged;`

```
void MyModernTab_SelectedSourceChanged(object sender, SourceEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source.OriginalString.EndsWith("Foo.xaml"))
    {
        var url = "/Pages/Foo.xaml";
        var bb = new BBCodeBlock();
        bb.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative), this, NavigationHelper.FrameTop);
    }
}
```